# PGF labels in groupplot vs. the list of figures

Tags: pgfplots, table-of-contents, captions

For my bachelor thesis I'm relying on pgf for my plots.

In the groupplot environment I create a node to label each subfigure, something like:

```
\node at (x,y) {
    \textbf{a)}
    \addtocounter{gifure}{1}
    \captionof{subfigure}[minimal name]{}
    \addtocounter{giure}{-1}
};
```

The `\addtocounter`'s are necessary for `\ref` to work properly.

To this point everything is fine, but when I create the list of fiures, latex
treates these `\captionof`'s like they belong to the previous image.
I included a minimal working example:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usepackage{caption}
   \captionsetup{width=\textwidth,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[blue,domain=-1:1] {1 - x^2 + x^4};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{The First Plot}
    \label{first plot}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!b]
    \centering
    \input{plots.tikz}
    \caption{Two beautiful plots.}
    \label{more plots}
\end{figure}
The first Plot \ref{first plot}. The second plots \ref{more plots}, \ref{2. plot a}, \ref{2. plot b}.
Everything works excellent!

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

plots.tikz:

```
% !TeX root = main.tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,
    horizontal sep =0.1\textwidth},
    height=0.45\textwidth,width=0.45\textwidth,]

    %%%%%
    % 1x1               
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$y_1$,
        xlabel=$x$,]
    \addplot[blue,domain=0:5,] {exp(-0.5*x)*sin(rad(x))};

    % subplot name
    \node[text width=0.3\textwidth,anchor=north west] (Subplot a) at (rel axis cs: 0.05,0.95)
    {
        \textbf{a)}
        \addtocounter{figure}{1}
        \captionof{subfigure}[Second plot first part]{\label{2. plot a}}
        \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    };


    %%%%%
    % 2x1           
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$y_2$,
        xlabel=$x$,]
    \addplot[blue,domain=-1:1,] {-x*x + 2*x};

    % subplot name
    \node[text width=0.3\textwidth,anchor=north west] (Subplot b) at (rel axis cs: 0.05,0.95)
    {
        \textbf{b)}
        \addtocounter{figure}{1}
        \captionof{subfigure}[Second plot second part]{\label{2. plot b}}
        \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    };

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do all that stuff manually. You're loading `subcaption`, so just add `list=true` as an option to that, and use `\subcaption` in the node. That is, use

```
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
```

and replace your labelnode with something like

```
\node[text width=1cm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] (Subplot a) at (rel axis cs: 0,1)
{\subcaption[Second plot first part]{\label{2. plot a}}};
```

I reduced the `text width`, set `inner sep` to zero, changed the coordinate to `(rel axis cs:0,1)`, and replaced all the content with a `\subcaption`. Result:

[image]