# Is a combined use of subcaption, tikzscale and groupplots possible?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subcaption, groupplots, tikzscale

I am just trying to get the "everything in one". I would like to have figures using

1. the groupplot library of pgfplots
2. subcaption to be able to reference to every single plot inside the groupplot. See also [PGF labels in groupplot vs. the list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265719/pgf-labels-in-groupplot-vs-the-list-of-figures), where the answer shows a nice way to set the labels without using space between the single plots.
3. the tikzscale package to render linewidths and font sizes precisely, while having plots that have precisely the width of `\linewidth`

Now the point is, that the tikzscale package induces that one `\includegraphics` instead of `\input`s the tikz file. And this seems to cause a problem with the counters used by subcaption. Here is a small MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{plots.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style = {group size=2 by 1,
                    horizontal sep=1cm,
                },
                width = 1/2*\linewidth-1cm,
                height = 0.2\textheight,
            ]

            \nextgroupplot
            \node[text width=1cm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs: 0,1) {\subcaption{\label{first}}};
            \addplot {x};

            \nextgroupplot
            \node[text width=1cm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs: 0,0) {\subcaption{\label{second}}};
            \addplot {x*x};     
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \input{plots.tikz}
        \caption{bla}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots.tikz}
        \caption{blub}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Besides the fact that this is not really a M**W**E, because I cannot label the same subcaptions twice (but this is of course not an normal use-case), the real problem is the labeling of the second figure: It isn't `(a)`, `(b)` but `(i)`, `(j)`. By varying the number of plots in the groupplot, the "starting index" also varies. If one has six plots, it will start at `(y)` and run into an counter error.

So my question is: What exactly is the problem and is a workaround existing without loosing the features of the list above?

Comment: Tikzscale must be executing the code 5 times, using different values of xscale and yscale.  Each time the subfigure counter is incremented (by two).

Comment: @John The question seems to be: Is it a bug of subcaption or of tikzscale? Anyhow, it feels like it should work also without an additional setcounter. (I wondered a bit, that it works, because the subcaption manual does not offer information about its counting)

Comment: The problem is that \stepcounter and \refstepcounter are global, so the usual trick of putting things inside a group won't help.  Putting \subcaption inside a tikzpicture is, at the very least, unusual practice.

Comment: @John: If it is unusual practise, what is the usual practise for groupplots?

Comment: I suspect the most usual approach is to give each plot its own title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `\setcounter` inside plots.tikz

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{plots.tikz}
    \setcounter{subfigure}{0}% assuming no other subfigures in figure
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style = {group size=2 by 1,
                    horizontal sep=1cm,
                },
                width = 1/2*\linewidth-1cm,
                height = 0.2\textheight,
            ]

            \nextgroupplot
            \node[text width=1cm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs: 0,1) {\subcaption{}\label{first}};% \label should go after
            \addplot {x};

            \nextgroupplot
            \node[text width=1cm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs: 0,0) {\subcaption{}\label{second}};% not inside
            \addplot {x*x};     
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \input{plots.tikz}
        \caption{bla}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots.tikz}
        \caption{blub}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```